# A question whether a transformation is 1-1 and onto or not if its vector space satisfies some condition

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, solution-verification

I'm  trying assignment questions and I was unable to solve this particular problem.

> Let V be the space of twice differentiable functtions on $\mathbb{R} $ satisfying $f''-2f'+f =0$. Define $T:V\to\mathbb{R^2}$  by $T(f) =(f'(0), f(0))$. Then $T$ is:

1. One -One or not.
2. Onto or not.

Using condition of $1-1$ I got $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(0)=g'(0)$ but one can say that $f=g$ from this information. So, I don't think $f$ is $1-1$.

I think $f$ is onto as for all $(x,y)$ belonging to $\mathbb R^{2} $  as $f$ can be chosen so that $f'(0) =x, f(0)=y$.

But I did not used condition $f''-2f'+f =0$ in my answers

So, are my answers correct?

Comment: First of all solve $f''-2f'+f=$. This will give some idea about one-one and onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solving differential equation $f''-2f'+f=0$. we have $f(x)=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x$.Then $f(0)=c_1$ and $f'(0)=c_1+c_2$. Let $f_1(x)=e^x$ and $f_2(x)=xe^x$. $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent(You can use **Wronskian**) and spans $\Bbb{R}^2$ (why).
Therefore, $e^x,xe^x$ form a basis. And matrix representation of $T$ is \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}. $T$ is invertible and hence $T$ is bijective.

**Added**: let $\alpha=\{f_1,f_2\}$ be a basis of $V$ and $\beta=\{\vec{e_1},\vec{e_2}\}$ be a standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$ .$$T(f_1(x))=(f'_1(0),f_1(0))=(1,1)=1\vec{e_1}+1\vec{e_2}$$ and $$T(f_2(x))=(f'_2(0),f_2(0))=(1,0)=1\vec{e_1}+0\vec{e_2}$$.Then the matrix representation of $[T]_\alpha^\beta$ is \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.

Comment: can you please tell how the matrix representation is as given in question?

Comment: @YannicMuller see my recent edits.